# Use of unresolved identifier - UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, identifier

I'm trying to make `uitableview` with days of the week. First should be always current day. But I have simple problem with import identifier. This is my code:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate {
 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

 //Define Days Of The Week

 let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
 let today = NSDate()

 let AddOneDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 1,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddTwoDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 2,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddThreeDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 3,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddFourDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 4,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddFiveDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 5,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddSixDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 6,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 func convertDaysFormater(date: String) -> String {
     let daysFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
     daysFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
     daysFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pl_PL")
     let convertedOneDay = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddOneDay!)
     let convertedTwoDays = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddTwoDays!)
     let convertedThreeDays = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddThreeDays!)
     let convertedFourDays = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddFourDays!)
     let convertedFiveDays = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddFiveDays!)
     let convertedSixDays = daysFormatter.stringFromDate(AddSixDays!)

     return convertedOneDay
     return convertedTwoDays
     return convertedThreeDays
     return convertedFourDays
     return convertedFiveDays
     return convertedSixDays

 }

 // Define Array

 let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

 let swiftBlogs = [convertedOneDay, convertedTwoDays, etc...]
```

Can't put convertedOneDay - 'Use of unresolved identifier' error. Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: You need to re-think this.  Start with, you can't return six times from a single function call.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with the given code, it's unlikely that an answer here will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of similar code for example:

```
let AddOneDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 1,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddTwoDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 2,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddThreeDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 3,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddFourDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 4,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddFiveDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 5,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let AddSixDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
     .Day,
     value: 6,
     toDate: NSDate(),
     options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Only the variable name and value change for each of these it would be more efficient to story this an in array of `NSDate`s. For example:

```
let futureDates:[NSDate] = {
    var futureDates = [NSDate]()
    for index in 1 ... 6 // Range starting tomorrow and going up to 6 days
    {
        let futureDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
            .Day,
            value: index,
            toDate: NSDate(),
            options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
        futureDates.append(futureDate!)
    }
    return futureDates
}()
```

This way it would be trivial to change what days you want to look at. You simply change the range to iterate over.

The problem you are running into is you are attempting to use `convertedOneDay` outside of its scope. Because you declare `convertedOneDay` in `convertDaysFormater` it can only be used in that function.

Your `convertDaysFormater` function could also be improved. Right now, you are not using the parameter and as Phillip Mills points out once you call `return` you exit the function so subsequent `returns` are not executed. I propose you change the function to accept one date and return one string like so:

```
func convertDaysFormatter(date:NSDate) -> String {
    let daysFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    daysFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    daysFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pl_PL")
    return daysFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

We can now use our `futureDates` and our `convertDaysFormatter` function to generate the `swiftBlogs` array you want. By saying something like:

```
let swiftBlogs:[String] = {
    var swiftBlogs = [String]()
    for date in futureDates
    {
        swiftBlogs.append(convertDaysFormatter(date))
    }
    return swiftBlogs
}()
```

We just take each date from `futureDates` and use `convertDaysFormatter` to return the appropriate string that we append to our array. In swift you can say this even more concisely by simply saying:

```
let swiftBlogs = futureDates.map{convertDaysFormatter($0)}
```

When I run this code I get that `swiftBlogs` is equal to:

```
["niedziela", "poniedziałek", "wtorek", "środa", "czwartek", "piątek"]
```